# Show that $1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 (n+1)} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, partial-fractions

Show that

$$1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 (n+1)} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

**Proof**

By Partial Fraction Decomposition

$$\frac{1}{n^{2} \left(n + 1\right)}=\frac{-1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}+\frac{1}{n + 1}$$

Summing the series

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 (n+1)} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} \right) \\
&= \overbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}}^{\text{Basel}} + \overbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1}\right)}^{\text{Telescoping}}
\end{align*}

Basel Series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Telescoping Series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = -1$$

Thus,

\begin{align*}
1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 (n+1)} &= 1 + \overbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}}^{\text{Basel}} + \overbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1}\right)}^{\text{Telescoping}} \\
&= 1 + \frac{\pi^2}{6} -1 \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align*}
$\blacksquare$

**Question**

I'm curious if that's a valid rigorous proof?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info *For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so.*

Comment: @MarkViola Please look at the proof closer. It is the sum of reciprocal squares plus the telescoping series which you can see to the direct right, which is $\frac{\pi^2}{6} -1 $. This is a well known equivalency of the basel series,

Comment: [Riemann's rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) is not [the theorem you are quoting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence#Relation_to_convergence), and neither of them is used in your proof. Actually, proving absolute convergence was useless. You did *not* rearrange your series. You simply used that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(x_n+y_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n$, where $x_n=\frac1{n^2}$ and $y_n=-\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: @Anne Bauval. So the proof doesn't need to show absolute convergence? I can edit it and remove that since it does what you've noted: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(x_n+y_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n$

Comment: I would omit the details of the partial fraction decomposition and just skip to that identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Anne pointed out in the comments, all you need to use is the following theorem:

> If $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } a_n = A,\quad
>  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } b_n = B,\ $ then $\
>  \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } (a_n+b_n) = A+B.$

Now just put $a_n =\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $b_n = -\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1}.$

Comment: Thanks Adam! So much clearer to me now.

Comment: @vengy you're welcome. I have had the exact same issue that you have had in your question. So long as $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } a_n\ $ and $
 \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } b_n\ $ both converge, there is no issue.